# Q: Unable to upgrade past 4.7.13

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

Since 4.7.13 on Wordpress I am unable to upgrade my CiviCRM install. I enclose an image of the error message I get.

[image: Error message when trying to upgrade]

Clicking on the *Retry* or the *Skip* buttons has no effect.

I can't see what's going wrong, as I've not had any problems before. I am running WordPress 4.7.2, have no extensions, and cleared the cache and template_c folder as instructed on this page

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+WordPress

Comment: What is in your civicrm log in `<wordpressroot>/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog` ?

Comment: @Aidan Sorry for the delay in responding. The details of that directory are: 

.htaccess, 56B size.

Lots of files with names such as 
CiviCRM.<lots of log numbers>.log.<more numbers>, size 598.1K - 2.2M.

Config.IDS.ini, size 1.7K.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a Javascript error. You should make sure again that the CiviCRM files are all in the correct place.

Then try to run the upgrade in Firefox with Firebug enabled and look for JS errors in Firebug and that will provide you the clue as to what the problem is.